# Take img tag from $scope with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Dear friends I'm tring to extract img tag from html code (loaded into scope by php calling) without using jquery!
Is it possible only with angularjs?
This is my sample:

```
<p align="justify" class="truncate">{{art.contenuto | htmlToPlaintext}}</p>
```

the scope art.contenuto has html code inside with  inside.
with filter htmlToPlainText I remove all html tag. Now I would take img tag and load into img src!
Is it possible?

UPDATE

I'm tring with this filter:

```
.filter('imgSrc', function() {
    return function(text) {
        return String(text).match(/<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>/);
        //return String(text).match(/<img\s[^>]*?src\s*=\s*['\"]([^'\"]*?)['\"][^>]*?>/);
    }
})
```

but the results are like this:

```
["<img height=\"300\" align=\"left\" width=\"272\" src=\"http://www.domain.it/images/sex/3modi.gif\" alt=\"Tre modi per provocare piacere dell'uomo con la stimolazione del Punto L\" class=\"fr-fin\">","http://www.domain.it/images/sex/3modi.gif"]
```

what's wrong?

Comment: You should probably parse the image URL in the controller and pass it to the `ng-src` attribute directly. Doing that in the template would be extremely hacky to impossible.

Comment: So there'isnt a way to create filter and take only img or src from scope?!
For example removing all non img tag?

Answer (score 0):

you can bind html directly using ng-bind. Only remember to sanitize it first

```
<p align="justify" class="truncate" ng-bind-html="art.contenuto"></p>
```

To sanitize in your controller:

```
$scope.art.contenuto = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.art.contenuto);
```

Comment: I would find only img tag!

Comment: I solve editing the php file that take valure! thanks